# forming a bitmap using enum in c

Tags: c

I want to understand how to form a bit map from enum and returned through function.

```
typedef enum colors{
      red = 0;
      blue = 1;
      ... 
      pink = 15;
 }colors;
```

these colors are set by bits. 1 for set and 0 if not present. so how can I form a bit pattern using this and return it through a function call.

eg. `funname(enum colors &pattern);` something like this.. I know this can be done by using bit fields in structure. But i want to know if it is doable by using enum?

Comment: An enum is just an integer with some named values, so anything you can do with an integer you can do with an enum.  In short, the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: i think something like this..http://code.google.com/p/bitwise-enum/

Comment: how do i set values then.. i mean how can i return the above enum to any calling function as U16 or short?

Comment: A bit field is not an enumeration.  It is combinatorial and can produce values that are not enumerated.  Enums are also signed integers by default, which is not ideal for bitwise operations.  While it can be used, enum is probably not the construct you want.

Comment: Comments about syntax: the first `colors` in the `enum` is not needed. Elements of `enum` are separated by commas, not semicolon. Since you define the type `colors`, remove `enum` from the parameter in the function call.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the values so that each color has only one bit set.

```
typedef enum colors{
      red   = 0x0001;
      blue  = 0x0002;
      green = 0x0004'
      ... 
      pink  = 0x8000;
 } colors;
```

Then you can check a value (e.g. `color&red == red`) to match. I don't think there's a simpler way.

If you want to return a color as a short, you can just `return (short)red`.

You can return multiple values by `return (red|green|blue)`

If you have a color with value 0, say white, then your `object_color&white==white` will always be true.

Comment: well if i want to return two or three values then how can i set the bits and return the whole value?

Comment: The return value will have to be an int eg void funname(int &pattern); since the OR'ed value is no loner a valid enum.

Comment: yes that't correct. then you need to get in an array, or one by one, using a function which will return an enum.

Comment: okay yeah i am getting it .. but my requirement is somethng like this.. lets say red blue and green are set.. then bits 0,1,2 should be set 111 would be the pattern int value as 7.. also can i do something like int myval = 0; myval | = blue; to set the 2nd bit.. also i just noticed that i started enum with value 1 it should be from 0.

Comment: if you assume 0 represents a color then all compound colors will have that color in it, that's not good.

Comment: You've only got 8 bits in use for 16 colours.

Comment: I have just given an example of colors to make it simpler.. actual program is different!

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest would be to reorder your enum constants in such a way that they contain the correct R, G and B components in them at dedicated bit positions:

```
// 8 colors assuming bit0=Blue, bit1=Green, bit2=Red:
typedef enum colors {
  Black,
  Blue,
  Green,
  Cyan,
  Red,
  Magenta,
  Yellow,
  White,
} colors;
```

You can then, of course, `OR` them if for some reason you don't want to use predefined combinations such as `Cyan`, `Magenta`, `Brown` and `White`.

If you have more than 8 colors and the resultant color pattern can have 2 bits per each component (blue, green and red), the above is trivially extended.

This is how you use the enums directly.

Now, if you have few colors, but the color patterns can be something like 8 to 24 bit long, you may want to have a look-up table (array) containing the color patterns and you'll index it using your `colors` enum, e.g.:

```
const unsigned long colorPattern[] =
{
  0x000000, // Black
  0x0000FF, // Blue
  0x00FF00, // Green
  0x00FFFF, // Cyan
  0xFF0000, // Red
  0xFF00FF, // Magenta
  0xFFFF00, // Yellow
  0xFFFFFF, // White
};

unsigned long getColorPattern(colors c)
{
  return colorPattern[c];
}
```

Comment: actually i tried this 'code' int main()
{
   enum colors
   {
     red = (1<<0),
     green = (1<<1),
     blue = (1<<2),
     grey = (1<<3),
   };
   short int a=0;

   a = a | green;
   printf("value of a is %d\n",a);
   a = 0;
   a = blue | green;
   printf("value of a now is %d",a);

return 0;
}  it is printing the values as 2, 6 which are the respective bit patterns but i wanted to try something without 1<< in the enum.

Answer (score 0):

yes i think it was quite simple. Thanks everyone for your inputs. Here is what I have got.

```
int main()
{
   enum colors
   {
     red = 0,
     green = 1,
     blue = 2,
     grey = 3,
   };
   short int a=0;

   a = a | (1<<green);
   printf("value of a is %d\n",a);
   a = 0;
   a = (1<< blue) | (1<<green);
   printf("value of a now is %d",a);

return 0;
}
```

so i can create a function that sets these bit patterns and returns int value as suggested above by Alex.